# Read the firebase realtime database subnode with IOS-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in firebase realtime database.

[image: Collection]

I can read the information name, address, cp, image, etc. But when I try to access "concesiones" I always receive a nil.

My code to read the information is this.

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        user.phone = dictionary["phone"] as? String
        user.address = dictionary["address"] as? String
        user.district = dictionary["district"] as? String
        user.city = dictionary["city"] as? String
        user.state = dictionary["state"] as? String
        user.country = dictionary["country"] as? String
        user.cp = dictionary["cp"] as? String
        user.imageProfile = dictionary["imageProfile"] as? String
        user.concesiones = dictionary["concesiones"] as? [String]
    }
    print(user.name)
    print(user.concesiones)
    self.setupViewInfo(user: user)
}, withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `concesiones` you have an array of a mix of strings (index 0 and 2) and numbers (index 1). Since you're soft-casting it to an array of only strings, the cast results in `null`.

With the current data structure, the best you can do is:

```
user.concesiones = dictionary["concesiones"] as? [AnyObject]
```

But you might also want to consider storing only one type of data under `concesiones`, to simplify processing.